# How do I replace both = and & simultaneously

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace both "`=`" and "`&`" in a string simultaneously.

I have string as "`=123&`", I want to replace "`&`" and "`=`"  with "" so that I can get "`123`" using preg_replace

Comment: Why do you need regular-expressions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$result = preg_replace('#(&|=)+#', '', "=123&");
```

`$result` now equals `"123"`.

I recommend using `str_replace` (it will be faster), but if you insist on using regex, here it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace("/[&=]/","",$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `str_replace()`

```
str_replace(array('&', '='), '', $string);
```